# How to replace NA's with blank value?

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R and I wonder if I can replace NA value (which looks like string) with blank, nothing

It is easy when entire table is `as.character` however my table contains double's as well therefore when I try to run

```
f <- as.data.frame(replace(df, is.na(df), ""))
```

or

```
df[is.na(df)] <- ""
```

Both does not work.

Error is like

```
Assigned data `values` must be compatible with existing data.
Error occurred for column `ID`.
Can't convert <character> to <double>.
```

and I understand, but I really need ID's as well as any other cell in the table (character, double or other) blank to remain in the table, later on it is connected to BI tool and I can't present "NA", just blank for the sake of clarity

Comment: Any particular reason why you cant to convert explicit NA's to ""? This usually creates more problems than it solves. If it is about exporting the data to e.g. Excel, the functions  usually contain parameters to convert NA to any text string you want.

Comment: The problem is I don't want any NA nor other. NA means it is blank, no one filled this cell (lets say I am importing it to csv file). So I dont care if ID's looks like this `3872872 <blank> 8743973` but I can't have them like `3872872 "NA"/0/"NULL"/any other text or integer 8743973`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column is of type double (numbers), you can't replace NAs (which is the R internal for missings) by a character string. And `""` IS a character string even though you think it's empty, but it is not.

So you need to choose: converting you whole column to type character or leave the missings as NA.

EDIT:

- If you really want to covnert your numeric column to character, you can just use `as.character(MYCOLUMN)`. But I think what you really want is:
- Telling your exporting function how to treat NA'S, which is easy, e.g. `write.csv(df, na = "")`. Also check the help function with `?write.csv`.

Comment: Wow. Though I've done it and didnt worked, must have omit it in the process of trying to figure it out myself tens of times. Brilliant. Thanks